# Is there any similar site like http://jsonfiddle.net

Tags: json

I am trying to share one big JSON data with my colleague but didn't find any online tool for that. So far got http://jsonfiddle.net which is exactly what i am looking for but unfortunately the JSON data is not getting saved. So its no use.

Can anyone please share similar sites if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the bug with JSONFiddle, it was fixed a while ago. Let me know if you have any other issues. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Nice Tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to share the code, maybe you could use this:

http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score -1):

One website that might do the job is https://jsonware.com You'll get a fixed URL with your JSON that can be shared with your colleague. Everything is online, no installation is needed.